# Karaf & Pax Web jetty specific SslConnectionFactory

Tags: jetty, apache-karaf, pax-web, fusefabric

I'm trying to setup a specific jetty SSL context factory inside Karaf (in fact, Fabric8 (www.fabric8.io)).

I do this directly into the jetty.xml file:

`<New id="sslContextFactory" class="fr.maatg.pandora.sl.jetty.GridSslContextFactory">
   ...
</New>`

When I start the container, Pax Web generate an exception ( full exception https://gist.github.com/jrevillard/adb8e0bc0b1e9b568a67):

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.maatg.pandora.sl.jetty.GridSslContextFactory not found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty [100]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:281)
    ... 16 more`

Could someone tell me how I can use my specific factory ?

Jerome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the pax-web-jetty bundle doesn't support a dynamic import of "third-party" packages you'll need to create an extra fragment bundle that contains this class and attach it to the pax-web-jetty bundle. A working sample on how to add this to pax-web-jetty can be found at [the pax web samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/jetty-config-fragment/pom.xml)

In short the fragment bundle manifest needs to contain a Fragment host. With the felix-bundle-plugin it needs to look like this:

```
<Fragment-Host>org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty</Fragment-Host>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to work. I face another exception now but it seems to be a problem on my side :-)